# Is there any annotation based version for spring web flow?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-webflow

I have been working on an infrastructure project that has a myriad of pages that used in numerous flow based scenarios. I eager to use a standard framework for facilitating this flows. I have a glance on spring web flow and I realize it is difficult to deal with all of the XML stuff like flow files. Could you please tell me is there an annotation base version instead of these XML files? Or Is there any other frameworks that use annotation based approach for this purpose. Moreover, I saw Seam framework, but like Spring Web Flow it has an XML based feature. Additionally, I read some articles about Netui Page Flows. Even though it has annotation based flows, as you know it is a very old framework and discontinued now.

I use this links:

[spring web flow support in intellij idea 12](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/07/spring-web-flow-support-in-intellij-idea-12/)

[Spring Web Flow Ref Book](http://dl.finebook.ir/book/5b/13566.pdf)

[spring web flow](https://dzone.com/refcardz/spring-web-flow)

Comment: I don't think there is a way to use Web Flow with only annotations. You might be able to so some/much/all of the supporting Spring set up that way, but I don't think WebFlow flow definition itself. IMO, part of what's nice about Web Flow is the single XML file for the flow itself. You can see the whole flow in one place (the Spring Eclipse tools even have a flow visualizer), and you can perform simple logic steps in the XML, sometimes without having to write any supporting Java code.

Comment: @dbreaux  Thanks for your response. Yes, I saw this nice feature, but due to developer mistaks on xml files, I have looking for object oriented tool that improve readability and maintainbility of our code. Xml files are error prone and I worried about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I need this xml based file for create a web flow for my JSP pages into my enterprise application, after month looking for best solutions and frameworks, finally I find [Spring Statemachine](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) for my porpuse. I put that here for someone in future that looks for object-oreinted state machine that can be used in her/his page flow.

Thank you Spring :)